# How to get Wikidata ID for an Wikipedia article by API?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

How to obtain Wikidata ID from English Wikipedia article name, also for redirects? Is there API call?

Example:

```
Karachi >> Q8660
Karaachi >> Q8660
```

How to approach changes in assignment? Now [Media in Karachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Media_in_Karachi&redirect=no) is redirect to [Media of Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_of_Pakistan) (Wikidata item [Q6805922](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6805922)), but can be own article later.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use Wikipedia API to create a query with property [pageprops](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageprops) and [resolving redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects=1&titles=ARTICLE_NAME
```

In your case, for Wikipedia articles *"Media in Karachi"* and *"Media of Pakistan"* you will get the same Wikidata item ID: [Q6805922](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects=1&titles=Media%20in%20Karachi). Same thing for *"Karaachi"* and *"Karachi"* → [Q8660](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects=1&titles=Karaachi).

Comment: How would you do the opposite? That is, get the article when you just have the Wikidata ID?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079989/how-to-get-wikipedia-page-from-wikidata-id/37086915#37086915

Comment: It doesn't work for e.g. with Isabel_II_del_Reino_Unido

Comment: @Leandro, [Isabel II del Reino Unido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabel_II_del_Reino_Unido) is in Spanish not in English Wiki, and it is normal page, not redirection. But [Elizabeth II](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Elizabeth_II&redirect=no) is redirection, so you can use https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects=1&titles=Elizabeth%20II or to get directly the wikidata id: https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects=1&titles=Isabel%20II%20del%20Reino%20Unido

Comment: @Termininja yes thanks, I supossed that could find any entity by name without using the wiki lang specification

Answer (score 4):

As well as the accepted answer you can also use the Wikidata API directly passing in a site and a title.

The docs are at https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities

Get the entity for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karachi:

- If you know the exact title: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Karachi
- With title normalization, for initial character capitalization fixes, and underscores (and possible more): https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Karachi&normalize=1

Comment: do you have an example of an issue solved by the `normalize` parameter?

Comment: Yes, a simple case would be titles=karachi will not return a result as the title is meant to be capitalized, normalize=1 will fix this.
I will update the answer.

Comment: If you mean "en" for English Wikipedia, all you need to do is change the "enwiki" part to some other wiki language, for example "dewiki" for German Wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do it in Google Sheets, and was able to do it with a formula like this. It assumes the Wikipedia title is in column B. Copy down to the rows you need

```
=IMPORTXML(concat("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects=1&format=xml&titles=",B1),"//@wikibase_item")
```

Another suggestion is to use the dump https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-page_props.sql.gz, 230Mb zipped